# Delphi TParallel.For - Cannot Capture Symbol

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing

I just know From Delphi XE7 there is Parallel.For which is cool. so I try to convert a small piece of code, such as:

```
procedure TestParallel;
var
  i, j, u, v: integer;
  map: array of array of integer;
begin
  SetLength(map, 101, 101);
  u := 100; v := 100;
  for i := 0 to u do
  begin
    for j := 0 to v do
    begin
      if (map[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        map[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

to :

```
procedure TestParallel;
var
  i, u, v: integer;
  map: array of array of integer;
begin
  SetLength(map, 101, 101);
  u := 100; v := 100;
  TParallel.&For(0, u, procedure(i: integer)
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    for j := 0 to v do
    begin
      if (map[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        map[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end);
end;
```

***UPDATE***

Yes, above code compiles, and the following is not (if the map array is passed as var parameter)

```
type
   data = array of array of integer;
procedure TestParallel(var map: data);
var
  i, u, v: integer;
begin
  SetLength(map, 101, 101);
  u := 100; v := 100;
  TParallel.&For(0, u, procedure(i: integer)
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    for j := 0 to v do
    begin
      if (map[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        map[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end);
end;
```

But unfortunately, the compiler says:

```
[dcc64 Error] Project2.dpr(70): E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'map'
```

So, how to make this work as simple as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code, identical to that in the question, compiles in both dcc32 and dcc64, on Delphi XE7 update 1.

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.Threading;

procedure TestParallel;
var
  i, u, v: integer;
  map: array of array of integer;
begin
  SetLength(map, 101, 101);
  u := 100; v := 100;
  TParallel.&For(0, u, procedure(i: integer)
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    for j := 0 to v do
    begin
      if (map[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        map[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end);
end;

begin
end.
```

The local variable `i` in `TestParallel` is unused, as the compiler observes, and should be removed. Not that it makes any difference.

I cannot explain why you are unable to compile this code. Either you are using a different compiler from me, or have different code from me.

---

**Update**

And indeed, from your question update, it turns out that you have not posted the code that does not compile.

The big lesson here, is never to post fake code. Always post real code, complete code if at all possible, as minimal as you can.

As for your real code, that you have just posted, that looks like this:

```
procedure TestParallel(var map: data);
var
  i, u, v: integer;
begin
  SetLength(map, 101, 101);
  u := 100; v := 100;
  TParallel.&For(0, u, procedure(i: integer)
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    for j := 0 to v do
    begin
      if (map[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        map[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end);
end;
```

That fails to compile because var parameters cannot be captured. The compiler has to be able to see that a capture is necessary when compiling the function that declares the variable. For a `var` parameter, the compiler has no knowledge of where the variable is declared. See [Anonymous Methods Variable Binding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Anonymous_Methods_Variable_Binding):

> A key feature of anonymous methods is that they may reference variables that are visible to them where they were defined.

You need to use something along these lines:

```
procedure TestParallel(var map: TArray<TArray<Integer>>);
var
  LocalMap: TArray<TArray<Integer>>;
  u, v: integer;
begin
  SetLength(LocalMap, 101, 101);
  TParallel.&For(0, high(LocalMap), procedure(i: integer)
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    for j := 0 to high(LocalMap[i]) do
    begin
      if (LocalMap[i][j] <> 0) then
      begin
        LocalMap[i][j] := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end);
  map := LocalMap;
end;
```

We declare a local which we can then capture. Then we can assign to the `var` parameter after the loop has completed. Well, we could equally assign before the loop starts but that feels semantically odd to me.

Comment: thanks. I found out that if   map is passed into the procedure as  var parameter, then it will not compile...

Comment: The code in the question does not pass the array as a var parameter. You might wonder why I always ask for a [mcve]. I hope that you can understand now why I do so.

Comment: Thanks. now I get your point...   have re-edited the question.

Comment: thanks.. any chance to make var work ? actually, i don't quite understand what you meant by 'capture'

Comment: See my update. No point continuing until you understand variable capture. I suggest that you read the documentation for Delphi anonymous methods. Have you done that yet?